# UISearchBar text doesn't start from right to left on a rtl language

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to enter a text to a searchbar on a rtl language, the problem is, when I try to do it with the rtl language as default on keyboard it starts in the wrong direction, when I switch keyboards from english to the rtl language it works just fine.

**current result**
[image]

**desired result**
[image]

Iv'e tried setting the searchbar semantic attribute to fore right to left but it doesn't seem to work.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it using UITextFiled containInstance property.
Just add a checking with language.

```
if myLanguage == "ar" {
        UISearchBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).textAlignment = .right
    }else{
        UISearchBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).textAlignment = .left
    }
```

Comment: Working for me, in case someone has to know how to change the cancel button text in the search bar use the following line of code.
`UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).title = "Custom title"`

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code (as you told):

```
 searchbar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Also make sure you are using *right-to-left language for simulator/device keyboard layout* when testing. It is not working with English keyboard layout properly.

It's helpful to disable "Connect hardware keyboard" (Hardware -> Keyboard -> "Connect hardware keyboard" -> remove checkmark) when testing on Simulator, in order to see keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your makeUIView function, both of them are needed:

```
searchBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
searchBar.searchTextField.textAlignment = .right
```